# how to use ajax result in click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony

i make a form in symfony when i submit form through ajax then i store (result.id) in a variable and then i used this variable in click function but the error occur invoiceid does not exist in new.html.twig
how to resolve this problem?
here is my code of ajax:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {              
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
    }).done(function( result ) {
        var invoiceid=(result.id);
        if(result.success) {
            $('#result').css({
                'color':'black',
                'background-color':'#8F8',
                'display':'Block',
                'width':'200px'
            });
            $('#result').html('Invoices Record Inserted');
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#result').hide();
            },3000);
        }
    });
    this.reset();
});
$("#edit").click(function(){         
    window.location.href= "{{ path('invoices_edit', {'id': invoiceid }) }}";  
});
```

Comment: You have no scope to `invoiceid` in click function, declare it as global

Comment: i declare invoiceid as global but same error

Comment: i delare like this:$(document).ready(function() {
  var invoiceid;

Comment: Are you getting value in `invoiceid`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your templating function `{{ path }}` is resolved before JavaScript even runs.
Your templating engine is unable to see JavaScript values, and the variable `invoiceid` does not exist in your template.

Comment: Nevermind, I've reviewed your code and your problem is completely different, see my updated answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. `{{ path }}` is being run by your templating engine on the server, while your JavaScript runs much later, in the browser.

Comment: i know but any solution ?